# Template de arquivo para Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

Com Maven Archetype é possível criar templates de projetos. 
E para template arquivo existe algo parecido?
Eu gostaria de criar um assistente de criação de arquivos. Algo parecido com a criação de Servlets, em que o assistente solicita o nome de Servelet, e o padrão de URL.